# Overlay images in MATLAB using predefined points

Tags: image, matlab

Basically what I'm trying to do is overlay two images using predefined points on each image.

The images will be of two different sizes probably or scaled differently, don't know this for sure yet. But the images are of the same thing. So what I want to do is say this spot on image one is the same as this spot on image 2. And do this for multiple spots and then have matlab resize or transform to get all those points lined up so that the two images can be overlayed. The thing thats confusing me is having matlab automatically adjust the images so that they can "fit" together.

I have no idea where to start on this, and was just hoping to get a general idea of what i may be able to do.

Just incase someone else knows how to do this I'll throw in what else I need to do. After the two images are on top of each other, one images will be a region map the other a real image. What I need matlab to do is count the amount of dots from the real image in each region of the map.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I guess he is talking about image rotation but using a slang word FLOP. It doesn't exits with reference to IP.

Comment: Dots or Pixels. Your question is misleading and is partly unclear. Can you please edit it or rephrase it so that we can suggest some good solution to you.

Comment: Here is a matlab's doc for different techniques of image alignement: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/registering-an-image.html

Comment: I edited it a bit, let me know if it helped at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called image registration which is a very common image processing task.  You wont need to write much code because matlab has built in functions for this.  You use the cp2tform to create a transform from the first to second image and can then apply the transform to the first image using imtransform function.  The code will look something like this assuming x,y coordinates of the control points are in an m by 2 matrix called points1 for image1 and points2 for image2.

```
  tform= cp2tform(points1, points2 , 'similarity');
  imtransform(image1, tform);
```

Comment: This works great, thanks.                                               Gonna add on though because I figured out what I was trying to do. So to set those specific points you use cpselect which brings up the two images letting you set points. You can then export these points into two arrays which you can put into the cp2tform.